# Complex insert statements

Tags: sql, insert

I want to ask is it possible to insert your own value in the table as well as select other values in other table? I have tried to come out with my select and insert statement but i'm missing one statement as i want to insert my own values in rather than referencing it.

All my required tables  have been created. And I wish to insert my own values like Type and rest of the insert values will be selected from other tables.

Below is my code: (Am i missing a statement?)

```
Insert Into Test (Test_Date, Testno, Examno, Serialno, Type, Hours)
Select S.Test_Date, E.Testno, S.Examno, S.Serialno, Type, (F.STARTED- F.ENDED) as hours
From Semester S, TIME F, TESTPAPERS e
Where S.Testno = F.Testno
  And E.Testno = 1
  and TYPE     = 'Non-FLight'; -- this is the statement that i wish to insert own values instead and not selecting.
```

Is it possible to do all in one insert statement ? I don't wish to update my table so many times just to insert type value.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put the value you would like for `Type` in your select statement:

```
Insert Into Test (Test_Date, Testno, Examno, Serialno, Type, Hours) 
Select S.Test_Date, E.Testno, S.Examno, S.Serialno, 'Non-Flight', (F.STARTED- F.ENDED) as Hours 
From Semester S, TIME F, TESTPAPERS e 
Where S.Testno = F.Testno And E.Testno = 1
```

Comment: sorry i would like to ask another question. For the hours, i use it as date data type. And when i subtract it, it just normally deduct. How can i subtract it in time format like hours ? I tried put datediff, timestampdiff, but it says invalid identifier. Thanks

Comment: @user976050 I would recommend posting another question to get good full answers.